# How to string.replace() more than once, while using a for loop?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'm making a Python program to edit a `.txt` file by replacing a few chars and substrings.

> **Steps:**
>
> I have to `readlines()` of an `input_file` and `append()` each line in
>   a `input_list`.
>
> Loop through that `input_list` and `replace()` a few stuff in each line.
>
> `append()` these edited lines in a `new_list`
>
> `write()` each item inside that `new_list` into an `output_file`.

But I think I'm doing it wrong... or maybe in a non-smart way, since my software is replacing chars that I don't want to be replaced.

Here, take a look at my code:

```
old = [] #input list
new = [] #output list
irrf_values = [] #list with len(old) tax values. I already have these values
aliq_pis = "000.6500"
aliq_cofins = "003.0000"

with open(input_file, "r") as f:
    old = f.readlines

i = 0
for line in old:
    irrf = irrf_values[i]

    line1 = line.replace(line[254:268], irrf)
    line2 = line1.replace(line1[332:333], "3")
    line3 = line2.replace(line2[433:434], "1")
    line4 = line3.replace(line3[438:439], "1")              
    line5 = line4.replace(line4[443:445], "00")             
    line6 = line5.replace(line5[479:487], aliq_pis)             
    line7 = line6.replace(line6[501:509], aliq_cofins)              
    line8 = line7.replace(line7[659:669], line[649:659])                
    line9 = line8.replace(line8[693:694], "0")

    newline = line9

    new.append(newline)
    i += 1

with open(output_file, "w") as g:
    for line in new:    
        g.write(line)
```

But when I run my program, all the "1's" in that line are replaced by "3"

Ex.:

Line1 from **input_file** (one of the lines that I want to edit)

```
1011015                   000000001057.870000000000000021.16                                                00000001057.8700000000000.0000000000000.00              00000001057.8700000000000.0000000000000.0000000000000.00                    2069726000017500000000000.0000000000000.00   00.00              T4N00000000000.00 00090000001     0                                           SP01101500000000000.0000.0001.05.00    OU000B A  00400010434020         NFSE   010100000001057.87000.000000000000000.00000.000000000000000.00000900                                                                  0                        N                         SP 00000260310000000000                002.00000  43402           0
```

Line1 of the **output_file** (after the replacements made by my software)

```
3033035                   000000003057.870000026033000023.36                                                00000003057.8700000000035.8700000000035.87              00000003057.8700000000035.8700000000035.8700000000035.87                    0069726000037500000000035.8700000000035.87   00.00              T0N00000000035.87 00090000003     0                                           SP03303500000000035.8700.0003.05.00    OU000B A  00000030030000         NFSE   030300000003057.87003.000000000000035.87003.000000000000035.87000900                                                                  0                        N                         SP 00000260330000026033                002.00000  03002           0
```

Line1 **manually edited** (this the output that i'm looking for)

```
1011015                   000000001057.870000000000000021.16                                                00000001057.8700000000015.8700000000000.00              00000001057.8700000000000.0000000000000.0000000000000.00                    2069726000017500000000000.0000000000000.00   00.00              T4N00000000000.00 00090000003     0                                           SP01101500000000000.0000.0001.05.00    OU000B A  00100011434000         NFSE   010100000001057.87000.650000000000006.88003.000000000000031.74000900                                                                  0                        N                         SP 00000260310000026031                002.00000  43402           0
```

Questions:

1. Is there any smarter way to do that? (replacing lots of stuff of a string while looping through a list)
2. Can anyone explain me what I've done wrong? (why my software is creating a weird output?)

Comment: 1/ yes, you can make a list out of your string, then assign directly by index or slice, then join back into a string. 2/ read the documentation. You are mostly using one function, so it shouldn't take too long.

Comment: You've hard-coded the string indexes, but unless your replacement values are always exactly the same length as the originals, things will be out of sync after the first replacement.

Comment: @njzk2 1) Do you mean something like `line = line[0:start] + edited_part + line[end:]` ?

Comment: not only that, but `str.replace` replaces all instances of whatever your first parameter is which means it is slicing your string, then finding all instances of whatever that slice happens to be and replacing it with the second one.

Comment: @Pardoido for example, yes

Comment: @DanielRoseman, i'm checking the len(before) len(after) of the strings... if they don't match, i'll get an error message.... but they aren't changing the values after/before

Comment: @RNar, let me see if I understood: if my line[0:1] corresponds to the char "1", every occurrence of the char "1" in my string will be replaced? I thought that by defining line[0:1], only that occurrence would be replaced...

Comment: no `replace(a , b)` replaces all substrings a with the substring b in your string

Comment: Besides that, you don't need to save your whole document in a list, since python handles files like iterables. just use `for lines in f` to iterate line by line through the file and then write it at the end of your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.replace(old, new)` will replace all occurrences of the `old` argument with the `new` argument.

So when you do `line.replace(line[254:268], irrf)` it will use the characters on your line in the range `[254:268]` and use that to search for all occurrences in the string to be replaced by `irrf`.

If you want to use the slicing like you're already doing, you can perform each replacement like

```
line1 = line[:254] + irrf + line[268:]
```

That could be simplified to a generic function with a signature like `def my_replace(input, replacement, start, stop)`.

You also don't need to keep assigning the result of your replacements to a new string, so you can happily do `line = my_replace(...)`.